# If $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic, $g(1+i)=0$, is $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> 1. Does there exist analytic functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, $g(1+i)=0$, such that $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is also analytic in all $\Bbb{C}$.
> 2. Does there exist non-analytic functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ such that $h(z)=f(z)+g(z)$ is analytic in all $\Bbb{C}$?

Can anyone help me and give me ideas and other useful information that I can use to solve this problem? I am really doubt about this exercise.

First of all, if $g(1+i)=0$ and analytic in all $\Bbb{C}$ it follows (I guess) that $g(z)=0$ $\forall z \in \Bbb{C}$. That means that I need to construct $f(z)$ such that $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{0}$ must exist and be finite. Does that mean that $f(z)\approx 0$?

Comment: Do you think that $g(z)=z-(1+i)$ is analytic?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you wrote about $g$. Do you believe that if $1+i$ is a zero of an analytic function $g$, then $g$ is the null function. What about $g(z)=z-(1+i)$ then?

Anyway, the answer is negative, because of $g(1+i)=0$, then $h$ is not even defined at $1+i$.

And if you define $f(z)=\overline z$ and $g(z)-\overline z$, then neither $f$ nor $g$ are analytic, but $f+g$ is the null function, which is analytic.

Comment: If $f$ had a zero at $1+i$ of order at least equal to the order wrt $g$, then the quotient turns out to be analytic at $1+i$. He may take $f(z)=\big(z-(1+i)\big)^2$ and $g(z)=z-(1+i)$ and $\big(f/g\big)= z-(1+i)$.

Comment: No. What happens in that case is that you can *extend* the quotient to an analytic function such that $1+i$ belongs to its domain. But the quotient itself is undefined there.